# API chuck norris jokes undefined

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm trying to call two different APIs. My idea is that when you click in the bottom, a random joke will appear in the screen. I have created two different functions to fetch the two different APIs. Then, I have used Math.random() two get a random number. If it's random > 50, one function gets executed and else the other. My problem is that the API data from the Chuck Norris API always returns Undefined and I'm struggling to see wha the mistake is.

This is my JS code:

```
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const joke = document.getElementById("joke-content");
const url = " https://icanhazdadjoke.com/";
const urlChuck = "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random";

button.addEventListener("click", getJoke = () => {
    const randomNumber = 100 * Math.random();
    return randomNumber > 50 ? getDadJoke() : getChuckJoke();
}
);

const getDadJoke = () => {
    fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => joke.innerHTML = data.joke)
}

const getChuckJoke = () => {
    fetch(urlChuck, {
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => joke.innerHTML = data.joke)
}
```

Comment: The `Chuck` API appears to return the joke using the `value` property, not the `joke` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the the Chuck Norris joke, you're referring to `data.joke` but it should be `data.value`:

```
const getChuckJoke = () => {
    fetch(urlChuck, {
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => joke.innerHTML = data.value)
}
```